# how to handle multiple inserts at once

Tags: mysql, transactions, locking

I need to run multiple queries at once. Below you can see an example.
How can I be sure that after I make an insert on table A and I store last insert id on a variable, it will be the right value inserted on the other tables if another insert occurs at the same time? Do I have to lock all tables, run my queries and then unlock tables? I read something about transactions. Do I need them? 
Thanks for any advice.

```
create table a (
id int not null auto_increment primary key,
name varchar(10)
) engine = innodb;

create table b (
id int not null auto_increment primary key,
id_a int
) engine innodb;

create table c (
id int not null auto_increment primary key,
id_a int)
engine innodb;

insert into a (name) values ('something');
set @last_id = last_insert_id();
insert into b (id_a) values (@last_id);
insert into c (id_a) values (@last_id);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this sequence

```
insert into a (name) values ('something');
set @last_id = last_insert_id();
insert into b (id_a) values (@last_id);
insert into c (id_a) values (@last_id);
```

The variable `@last_id` is global, but unique to your specific session.  Therefore, once it is set, the value doesn't change unless you change it again.

As for last_insert_id(), specifically the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) states

> The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis.

So it does not matter what other connections do.  The inserts into `b` and `c` are guaranteed to use the id generated for `a`.

Comment: Hi Richard. Thanks for the quick reply. So with these queries I can be sure that the sw I'm writing will have no problem even though more clients will insert data on the same table at the same time. It'a good new :)

Comment: Thanks to all. I will give you an upvote to everyone for the time you've dedicated me as soon as I'll have enough reputation. It seems that I need 15 points. Please forgive me.  Reached score and done as promised :)

Comment: +1 Hallo Richard. Interesting thread. If something goes wrong after first insert (power loss or any other problem) I lose data integrity. Please correct me if I'm wrong. To avoid this is not necessary a transaction?

Comment: @nick That is an interesting case. I would worry about other things, but you are right, if you `lose power` between `insert a` and the rest, they would be disconnected. I would assume there would be other things to clean up as well when such a thing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Per the MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) `last_insert_id()` only applies to the current session.

> The ID that was generated is
>   maintained in the server on a
>   per-connection basis. This means that
>   the value returned by the function to
>   a given client is the first
>   AUTO_INCREMENT value generated for
>   most recent statement affecting an
>   AUTO_INCREMENT column by that client.
>   This value cannot be affected by other
>   clients, even if they generate
>   AUTO_INCREMENT values of their own.
>   This behavior ensures that each client
>   can retrieve its own ID without
>   concern for the activity of other
>   clients, and without the need for
>   locks or transactions.

Comment: Thanks Suroot. I needed some confirm from people more skilled than me. :)

Answer (score 1):

If I were doing this, I would probably open a `transaction` as referenced http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

If you were using a framework like CodeIgniter, you would have access to a database abstraction layer that would work in a similar fashion, for example, http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html

Comment: Hi Mark. Thanks for your reply. I'm not using any framework. I'm writing a simple php application on my own that will run within a little office with different users that will populate the db. Based on Richard's answer I don't need any transaction.

Comment: Transactions are probably most useful if you have many users trying to update database records at the same and you need to prevent conflicts.  I once used transactions when working with an Oracle database application where data integrity was critical.  Most of my web applications have a small number of users and MySQL's basic functionality is more than sufficient, so Richard's answer is most applicable.